# how to retrieve an innerHTMLvalue from html tag <a>

Tags: html, asp.net, httpwebrequest

i use HttpWebRequest Method in asp web Page to read a page and import that page to my own page.in that page i have to retrive a specific Value (price) that reside in a  tag.
used code is this:

```
var req = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.somewhere.com/webservice/price_live.php?new=1&bg=f0f4f6&upc=196900&dc=FF0000&obc=f9f9f9&oc=09334d&ebc=ffffff&ec=09334d&hbc=09334d&hc=ffffff&fs=13");
            req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
            var res = req.GetResponse();

            Stream dataStream = res.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string ResponseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            res.Close();
            this.TextBox1.Text = (ResponseFromServer);
```

this code serves me whole html page, inside of that page exist  tag like this:

```html
<td class="text-left" ><a id="Goal" style="color:#FF0000" href="http://www.somewhere.com" target="_blank">127,000</a></td>
```

now how can i have "127000" and save that?!

Comment: note : i want to save that value in server side not client side.i mean i need to  find that tag, read value, then save to DB.all of this must be in server side i think.if there is a way to fetch value via jquery and can pass that to server! please tell me..also because all html page extracted in textbox, is there a way to find tag via string operations and if can , how?!......Thanks

Comment: Use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this, to store the Value of the Anchor into a new variable:

```
var linkval = document.getElementById('goal').innerHTML;
```

It will store the Value to the variable "linkval".

Comment: or you can use the parseInt(linkval) to convert that String into a Integer for using into math functions.

Comment: i want save that value in server side Not client side

Comment: You can do it by sending an AJAX call from the JS to the PHP file which will handle that Value through GET or POST Method

Answer (score 0):

since

```html
<a id="Goal" style="color:#FF0000" href="http://www.somewhere.com" target="_blank"> 
is first child of  <td class="text-left" >
```

therefore you can do in javascipt like below

```js
$('td:first-child a').text();
```

```
and then convert it to a number for further usage
```

Comment: i want save that value in server side Not client side .for saving in server side how can i do that